# Noise when pedalling

Tags: chain

What is causing [this noise](https://goo.gl/photos/9PvUpEmxKraTuZnD9)? Is it normal?

Comment: What noise?  What does it sound like?  Can you tell where it's coming from?  Does it happen when only when you're pedalling hard?  Does it happen only when you're out of the saddle?

Comment: I edited my post so that the video reference is more obvious. I think that the noise is caused by a friction between the chain guard and the chain itself.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise it was a video, since my browser wouldn't play it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source:

[image: source]

The chain and the other thing (I'd love to know what it's for by the way) were too close. The image is showing them after the adjustment.

Comment: The "other thing" appears to be cable housing. You haven't told us if that hub is an [IGH](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/1728/8273). If so then I'd guess it's the gear change cable.

Comment: A badly positioned cable, a manufacturing fault!

Comment: @Carel Well, it's my fault I think: When I was tightening the hub (I had taken the wheel off to change the tube), the cable rotated clockwise too. I had to push it away from the chain while tightening the big screw.

Comment: Yep, the sound is of the chain hitting something.

Comment: Hey @Yassine, you should accept your own answer to your question.  Nice find by the way!